# Executing an insert into postgres using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert data using psycopg2 into postgres. Here is the psuedo code I have. It seems to run without error but when I use navicat to check, it doesn't seem to update in the database. I did restart navicat to be sure.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbname user=username password = ****  host='localhost'")
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Here I tried a straight execute and a mogrify.

```
cur.mogrify("""INSERT INTO database (date, id) VALUES (now(), %s );""" % (user,))
cur.execute
```

I also tried this instead of the mogrify

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO database (date, id) VALUES (now(), %s );""" % (user,))
```

I can query a select statement but insert doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Did you execute `commit` after insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

commit the data?

```
conn.commit()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13479681)

Comment: @JulienBernu i thought its only possible answer. sorry:)

Comment: Just for clarification, after executing you still need to commit the data using the function conn.commit()